# jq build string from multiple levels

Tags: jq

I have the following JSON

```
  {
    "count": 2,
    "load_arg": {
      "limit": 100
    },
    "limit": 100,
    "result": [
      {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "Item1",
        "parts_list": {
          "subattributes": {
            "1234": {
              "chassisid": 111236,
              "part_attributes": {
                "subattributes": {
                  "134322": {
                    "attribute_id": 27,
                    "attribute_value": 3
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "1235": {
              "chassisid": 76,
              "part_attributes": {
                "subattributes": {
                  "192134": {
                    "attribute_id": 17,
                    "attribute_value": "steel"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 4321,
        "name": "Item2",
        "parts_list": {
          "subattributes": {
            "2212": {
              "chassisid": 93245,
              "part_attributes": {
                "subattributes": {
                  "76423": {
                    "attribute_id": 17,
                    "attribute_value": "plastic"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "65": {
              "chassisid": 2,
              "part_attributes": {
                "subattributes": {
                  "1285": {
                    "attribute_id": 27,
                    "attribute_value": 94
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }      
    ],
    "offset": 0
  }
]
```

and I'm trying to get jq to output the following from the results array

```
Item1: has a cover made of steel and requires part ID 27 to be 3
Item2: has a cover made of plastic and requires part ID 27 to be 94
```

I know some basic jq queries but I'm strugglig with grabbing a top level value and then building a string using some specific child values. In my JSON each result could have 10's of subattributes and not all of them are the same so I'd need to search for the attribute ID 17

Effectively I'm trying to pull (pseudo code as I know it's not right)

```
.[].result[].name + ": has a cover made of " + .[].result[].parts_list.subattributes[].part_attributes[][] | select(.attribute_id == 17).attribute_value + " and requires part ID 27 to be " + [].result[].parts_list.subattributes[].part_attributes[][] | select(.attribute_id == 27).attribute_value
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on your way:

```
def id2value($id): .. | objects | select(.attribute_id == $id) | .attribute_value;

.result[]
| "\(.name): has a cover made of \(.parts_list | id2value(17))"
```

With your input and using the -r command-line option, the above produces:

```
Item1: has a cover made of steel
Item2: has a cover made of plastic
```